# How to print JSON values with keys starting with special characters using angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

When I try to print using @place it throws error while the other keys are accessible.

[{
"ID": "001",
"Name": "Eurasian Collared-Dove",
"Type": "Dove",
"Scientific Name": "Streptopelia",
"@place": "New York"
}]

This is the error I am getting:
Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [@] at column 6 in expression [bird.@place], expected identifier or keyword at column 7 in [{{bird.@place}}]

The ***component.ts*** file is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';  

@Component({  
  selector: 'app-root',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})  
export class AppComponent {  
  title = 'JSON to Table ';  
  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }  
  arrBirds: string [];  

  ngOnInit () {  
    this.httpService.get('./assets/birds.json').subscribe(  
      data => {  
        this.arrBirds = data as string [];   // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.  
        // this.arrService = JSON.stringify(data);  
        console.log(this.arrBirds);  
      },  
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {  
        console.log (err.message);  
      }  
    );  
  }  
}
```

The ***component.html*** file is like this:

```
<table *ngIf="arrBirds">
      
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name of Bird</th>
                  <th>Type of Bird</th>
                    <th>Place</th>
      </tr>

      
      <tr *ngFor="let bird of arrBirds">
          <td>{{bird.ID}}</td>
              <td>{{bird.Name}}</td>
                  <td>{{bird.Type}}</td>
                    <td>{{bird.@place}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo with your capital P (instead of small p)?

Comment: You could try bracket notation `bird['@Place']` instead of the dot notation.

Comment: @Guilhermevrs that was a mistake. But still after using p instead of P I am getting the same error.

Comment: @MichaelD the ui displays bird['@place'] instead of printing the values.

Comment: @SoubhagyaSahoo: Please show how and where you're trying to access the property.

Comment: @MichaelD I have updated the post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment, you could use the bracket notation instead of the dot notation.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let bird of arrBirds">
  <td>{{ bird['ID'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ bird['Name'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ bird['Type'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ bird['@place'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xbk3lz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML I don't know any other method to call a property. The only solution I can see is to do a getter.

In TS

```
get place() {
    return bird['@Place']
}
```

In HTML

```
{{ place }}
```